# How to display a web page using QT/C++

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to display a web page using the below code

```
    QWebView *view = new QWebView();
    view->load(QUrl("qrc://images//sample page.html/"));
    view->show();
```

sample page.html is added to project resources/Images. The web page frame is loading, but I can't see any html data.

I tested with the below web url and it loaded the page

```
   view->load(QUrl("http://www.google.com/"));
```

Comment: Thanks to all, I found the issue view->load(QUrl("qrc:/Images/Folder Location.html"));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to go through a few steps as follows:

1) Get the `QWebPage` object:

```
 QWebPage *page = view->page();
```

2) Get the `QWebFrame` object:

```
 QWebFrame *frame = page->currentFrame();
```

3) Call the `toHtml` member function on the current frame:

```
 QString html = frame->toHtml();
```

Of course, you will need to add appropriate error checks in between.